# Overwrite IE Emulate mode to IE8 from iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I have a scenario where my webpage loads in IE7 but it has an iframe which needs to be loaded in IE8.

Parent page uses below meta tag which cannot be changed at all now.

```
<meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' />
```

I tried with below meta tags but no use.

```
<meta content='IE=EmulateIE8' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' />  
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
```

Is there anyway to change to IE8 from the iframe ?

Comment: break out of the iframe. if(self !== top) top.location.href = location.href

Comment: @MichaelDibbets What does this do ?

Comment: force the iframe to become the main page.

Comment: but our iframe is like a plugin and should be loaded within the predefined Ext JS Tab. When i do what you said, it opens the tab as main window.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, only real practical solution if you ** must ** support IE7(who uses it these days?)

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]><!-->
All your current mark up here.
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
Recreate what you have functional for IE7 and below
<![endif]-->
```

The ie7 part will be hidden by comments in all other browsers, and only show in ie7 or below.